# Compare svg files in dart/flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, svg

I have two svg files from network. They are similar in content but with different filenames. Is there a way, in dart or flutter, I could compare these files content?

I want to do something like:

```
if(fileOne.svg == fileTwo.svg){//do something here with similar files}
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SOF.

You can compare two files from assets by reading them as bytes:

```
import 'package:flutter/services.dart' show rootBundle;


ByteData bytes1 = await rootBundle.load('assets/fileOne.svg');
ByteData bytes2 = await rootBundle.load('assets/fileTwo.svg');
```

Then compare `bytes1` and `bytes2`